# Remove items from object array which has fields present in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have an array like the following :

```
selected = ["ID-1", "ID-2"];
```

and an array of objects like

```
objectArray = [
    {
        "id":"ID-1",
        "description":"Desction goes here",
        "another_filed":"Another Value"
    },
    {
        "id":"ID-2",
        "description":"Desction goes here",
        "another_filed":"Another Value"
    },
    {
        "id":"ID-3",
        "description":"Desction goes here",
        "another_filed":"Another Value"
    }
]
```

Now I need to remove the items from the `objectArray` which has an `id`, which is present in the `selected` array. So in the above case, I need to remove the first and second items from the `objectArray` as the corresponding ids are there in the `selected` variable and the result should only have one object which has the id value 3. How can I do this ?

Comment: `objectArray = objectArray.filter(elem => !selected.includes(elem.id));`

Comment: does *remove* means to keep the same object reference of the array? have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Below is a worked solution:

```js
const selected = ["ID-1", "ID-2"]

const objectArray = [
  {
    id: "ID-1",
    description: "Desction goes here",
    another_filed: "Another Value",
  },
  {
    id: "ID-2",
    description: "Desction goes here",
    another_filed: "Another Value",
  },
  {
    id: "ID-3",
    description: "Desction goes here",
    another_filed: "Another Value",
  },
]

const res = objectArray.filter(({ id }) => !selected.includes(id))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const selected = ["ID-1", "ID-2"];

const objectArray = [
    {
        "id":"ID-1",
        "description":"Desction goes here",
        "another_filed":"Another Value"
    },
    {
        "id":"ID-2",
        "description":"Desction goes here",
        "another_filed":"Another Value"
    },
    {
        "id":"ID-3",
        "description":"Desction goes here",
        "another_filed":"Another Value"
    }
]

const result = objectArray.filter(o => !selected.includes(o.id))

console.log("result", result)
```